# Editing shapefiles in Python via new Writer object isn't working

Tags: python, gis, shapefile

I'm currently following a Python geospatial analysis tutorial book by Joel Lawhead, and I'm running into an error when trying to edit shapefiles.

The shapefile I'm using is available a http://git.io/vLd8Y. I'm running my code in a Jupyter Notebook on python3.

This is my code. I'm simply reading in a shapefile as a Reader object `r`, and creating a new Writer object `w` with the same shapetype as `r`. Then, I'm attempting to attach the records from `r` to `w`.

```
import shapefile
r = shapefile.Reader("NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO")
w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)
w.fields = list(r.fields)
w.records.extend(r.records())
```

However, I'm running into this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-ceee096fbafa> in <module>()
      6 w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)
      7 w.fields = list(r.fields)
----> 8 w.records.extend(r.records())

AttributeError: 'Writer' object has no attribute 'records'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: This is a change with PyShp 2. I was unable to make the PyShp 2 writer object work so reverted to pip install `pyshp==1.2.12` where `w.records.extend(r.records())` works.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this same issue. It seems that `w.records.extend(r.records())` is no longer possible to do in the new version of pyshp. The correct method to do this is now:

```
for shaperec in r.iterShapeRecords():
   w.record(*shaperec.record)
   w.shape(shaperec.shape)
```

Please see an explanation for the change and more context around the above code [here](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/issues/113).

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the problem you've described.  I started with:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.4 (default, Oct  9 2017, 12:07:29) 
>>>
```

And install the `pyshp` module:

```
$ pip install pyshp
...
Successfully installed pyshp-1.2.12
```

And now:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec  1 2017, 09:21:53) 
[GCC 6.4.1 20170727 (Red Hat 6.4.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shapefile
>>> r = shapefile.Reader("NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO")
>>> w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)
>>> w.fields = list(r.fields)
>>> w.records.extend(r.records())
>>> len(w.records)
130
```

Do the `python` and `pyshp` versions you are working with match what I am using? If not, can you update your question to include the specific details of  your environment?